# Promise handle .catch and .then at once

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'd like to use one handler to manage the below promise regardless of `catch` or `then`. Is there a bluebird method for this? I've tried `.finally` and `.done` with no success.

```
var example = function(throwError){
  return Promise.resolve().then(function(){
    if(throwError) throw new Error("test error")
    return throwError
  })
}

example(true).SOMETHING(function(value){
  console.log(value) // error
})

example(false).SOMETHING(function(value){
  console.log(value) // false
})
```

I want to stop writing code like this.

```
function myPromiseCatch(){
  return myPromise
    .apply(null, _.values(arguments))
    .catch(function(e){
      return e
    })
}
```

Comment: How did `finally` not work?

Comment: Finally is throwing the error here's the test https://gist.github.com/reggi/db97369a07bb4df8d5f5

Comment: @Bergi - In my own test `.finally()` doesn't seem to pass the resolved or rejected value through to the callback and it doesn't seem to stop the exception either though it appears to be rethrowing the exception after the `.finally()` callback is called.  And the Bluebird doc for it really doesn't explain any of this.

Comment: @Bergi - does `.finally()` always have to be preceded by a `.catch()` in order to stop an exception from getting rethrown?

Comment: @jfriend00: Followed, rather :-) But yes, `finally` does rethrow exceptions, I'm not sure whether OP wants/needs that.

Comment: Ideally one handler to rule them all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your idea Thomas, here's another fairly simple possibility:

```
// create method that will always get called whether reject or resolve
Promise.prototype.always = function(fn) {
    return this.then(fn, fn);
};

// test function to resolve or reject based on input
function example(throwError){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (throwError) throw new Error("test error")
    resolve(throwError);
  });
}

// test that will resolve
example(false).always(function(value){
  console.log("always: " + value); // false
});

// test that will reject
example(true).always(function(value) {
  console.log("always: " + value); // error
});
```

This generates the following output:

```
always: false
always: Error: test error
```

So, the value is passed in both cases.  You could check its type if you needed to, but if you really need to know whether it was resolved or rejected, then separate handlers is probably the proper recipe anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's the sane solution for this unorthodox request. I wonder why I didn't think of it…

Comment: @Bergi - it sure seems like the Bluebird doc for `.finally()` is missing some very important information about rethrowing and about not having any value.

Answer (score 0):

> regardless of `catch` or `then`

Just use them *both*:

```
example(…).catch(function(err){ return err; }).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

There's no single library method for this as that's a quite strange pattern. If you don't need the result, go with [`finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html), if you care about the outcome use [`reflect`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html).

Comment: Tried `reflect` and that's not being called, and finally throws an error instead of catching it.

Comment: What do you mean, "reflect is not being called"? `reflect` doesn't take a parameter, it just returns a new promise to which you have to chain your usual `.then(console.log)`

Comment: Then that's not what I want :(

Answer (score 0):

I do realize that this is dangerous because it takes the error out of the chain, but it works.

```
Promise.prototype.thenCatch = function(fn){
  return this
    .catch(function(e){
      return e
    })
    .then(fn)
}
```

And to use.

```
example(true).thenCatch(function(value){
  expect(value).to.exist
    .and.be.instanceof(Error)
    .and.have.property('message', 'test error')
}).thenCatch(done)


example(false).thenCatch(function(value){
  expect(value).to.equal(false)
}).thenCatch(done)
```

Comment: Anyone have any better name ideas? `catchThen` or `thenCatch` or something totally different? @Bergi?

Comment: I'd call that `ignoreError` and move the `.then(fn)` part outside (to be called simply as `.ignoreError().then(function(value){…})`)

Comment: At first I liked `ignoreError()` or just `ignore()` and `ignoreThen()` however I realized it doesn't really convey that the `then` after may have the error object in it. Your not ignoring the error, you're returning it.

Comment: Ideally with your method `ifErrorReturn()` and for the one above `ifErrorReturnThen()` :/

Comment: Sure, name it whatever you deem the most descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.reflect() could be used in this situation. It basically gives you back the promise after it has settled (either fulfilled or rejected). Example:

```
function good() {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
}

function bad() {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("bad"));
}

function check(p) {
    if (p.isRejected()) {
        console.log('Rejected', p.reason());
    } else {
        console.log('Fulfilled', p.value());
    }
}

good().reflect().then(check);

bad().reflect().then(check);
```